# SQL - adding category to string value (mapping table)

Tags: sql, database, mapping

I'm trying to reproduce a mapping that I previously got from an external excel file into a SQL query. 
I have specific errors as string (ex. "aborted", "timeout"). A simplified example:

```
count   last_error
452     user_aborted
889     timeout
212     request_denied
98      blacklisted_by_admin
789     login_unsuccessful
340     country_not_available
```

I would like to map these into categories I have defined, so that the result would be a new column with the error category:

```
count   last_error                 error_category
452     user_aborted               user 
889     timeout                    tech
212     request_denied             risk
98      blacklisted_by_admin       risk
789     login_bad                  user
340     country_not_available      tech
```

What is the best way of doing this? I have about 40 errors, and six categories.

Comment: Add a new column and update the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `case` statement like this

```
case 
    when last_error in ('user_aborted', 'login_bad') then 'user'
    when last_error in ('request_denied', 'blacklisted_by_admin') then 'risk'
    when last_error in ('timeout', 'country_not_available') then 'tech'
end as error_category
```